# Xamarin Studio Rebuilds Every Time (PCL + iOS + MVVMCross)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Every time I start my iOS project, Xamarin Studio is building the code which takes about 40 seconds... even if I haven't changed any code/settings. Can someone point out what I've done wrong? Here are some details -

1. A new simple PCL + iOS project doesn't rebuild every time so I'm assuming it must be a setting somewhere in my larger project?
2. I'm referencing Release build MvvmCross DLLs from a clone of `MvvmCross-Binaries` which are outside the project directory (not NuGet)
3. A build output of a simple re-run with no code changes is on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/VePjUB2s)
4. My environment details are below

Is there anything else I can provide to help triage this?

```
Xamarin Studio
Version 5.7 (build 661)
Installation UUID: 34bb5f0c-bdbc-4184-bbd0-b6241f44d933
Runtime:
    Mono 3.12.0 ((detached/a813491)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 312000068

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 6.1.1 (6611)
Build 6A2008a

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 8.6.0.51 (Indie Edition)
Hash: dfb682f
Branch: 
Build date: 2015-01-08 13:39:32-0500

Xamarin.Android
Version: 4.20.0.28 (Starter Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/simonmatthews/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
Java SDK: /usr
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Build Information
Release ID: 507000661
Git revision: b70bab61da996da29045ea8ee8aed1a6faedbe78
Build date: 2015-01-05 16:31:31-05
Xamarin addins: 82f6c71490562d6cd125a09287f441902fdac3d7

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.10.1
Darwin Simons-MacBook 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0
    Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014
    root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: sounds like a problem with the xam tooling - maybe try xam support from your account on their store

Comment: Thanks Stuart (also thank you for all you do with MvvmCross.. it is awesome!). Unfortunately as I have an Indie license so I don't get email support, and there's nothing I could find in the forums/help. I posted this same question on the forum a couple of days before SO but haven't had any responses.

Comment: Email them anyway... I'm sure they want to know about and fix bugs ;)